# Gradle is not able to Sync upon fresh installation of Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Please help me solving this problem,

After a fresh installing on the android studio on my mac machine, I started with a problem with Gradle sync failed due to not being able to apply plugin. com.andriod.application

details say:

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Users/mohamedabaza/.android/build-cache.lock"
```

note: mohamedabaza is my PC name.

Also there is IDE fatal error says:

`Unable to read anonymization settings, not reporting any values: /Users/mohamedabaza/.android/analytics.settings (Is a directory)”`[IDE Fatal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARniq.png)

[Gradle fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBmIL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install android studio whilst you have a strong internet connection.It helped me a lot.

Comment: Thank you, I think that might help. I will try to raise my internet speed. What is the minimum speed that you recommend?

Comment: Well,I think 5,3 to 7Mb/s is decent enough.

Comment: I've upgraded to 15 mbps download speed and re-downloaded and reinstalled the program but still I have the same problem